# Turn on flashlight

Tags: android, camera, toggle, flashlight

I'm sorry for posting another question among all other simmilar ones but none of the questions that I've tried have worked. I'm trying to turn on the flashligh. Here is my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
    android:required="false" />
```

And this is my code for turning the flashlight on:

```
    Camera cam = Camera.open();     
    Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
    p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
    cam.setParameters(p);
    cam.startPreview();
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your device can handle FLASH_MODE_TORCH ? 
camera.getParameters().getSupportedFlashModes(); 
check if FLASH_MODE_TORCH is in the list returned by this call.

Comment: It's on a Galaxy Nexus and I already have that check, I just choose not to include it in the code snippet to focus the attention of the reader. The check doesn't return null.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"/>
```

Take care to add this on the right part of the manifest!
Take a look on the model here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

My code turning on the flash light looks like this:

```
public void myFlash (View view) {

    Context context = this;

    context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);

    Camera cam = Camera.open();
    Camera.Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
    p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
    cam.setParameters(p);
    cam.startPreview();

    //cam.stopPreview();
    //cam.release();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this [link](http://coderzworld.blogspot.in/2015/01/how-to-create-flash-light-on-android.html) will help you . I found this working for me.